# If a person does good deeds throughout his life but never believed in God, will he go to hell?

Tags: non-muslim, belief, hell

If a person is good person throughout his life,

But does not believe in God, in other words a Non-Muslim. Will he/she go to hell?

I think of this question when about reading Alexander Fleming, that he was a Good person, he did very well for the mankind, but he was Roman Catholic (according to [nndb](http://www.nndb.com/people/696/000091423/)).

Or some philanthropist, who do charity.

Will people like him, go to hell..? Because they do not believe.

As far as I know, a person who does not believe will go to hell in afterlife.

Comment: Are you talking about people who do not believe in Islam or do not believe in God? The two are very different.

Comment: I meant Non-muslims,..

Comment: If they believe in 1 GOD then there is a chance. But if they wont there is no chance a/c to QURAN because shirk is the top level sin which can't be forgive.

Comment: What if they do not do Shirk, they are Atheist...

Comment: http://islamqa.info/en/113901

Comment: That is what only Allah knows, because in more than one places our Prophet said that service to humanity comes before service to God. And many hadiths also prove service to humanity to be superior, depending on the deeds that person can go to heaven or hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained it before there are two kinds of ignorant: 1.Culpable ignorant 2.Inculpable ignorant

**The first group** deserves to be punished due to neglecting the duty of finding the TRUTH. Although they have the opportunity to go in search of convincing answers for a few crucial and fundamental Questions about their destiny and eternity! they irresponsibly ignore it. see how the verse is interpreted by a Hadith from Imam Kadim (peace be upon him)

> **رُسُلاً مُبَشِّرينَ وَ مُنْذِرينَ لِئَلاَّ يَكُونَ لِلنَّاسِ عَلَى اللَّهِ حُجَّةٌ بَعْدَ الرُّسُلِ وَ كانَ اللَّهُ عَزيزاً حَكيماً**
>
> **apostles, as bearers of good news and warners, so that mankind may not have any argument against Allah, after the [sending of the]
>   apostles; and Allah is all-mighty, all-wise.(4:165)**
>
> **عَنْ هِشَامِ بْنِ الْحَكَمِ قَالَ قَالَ لِي أَبُو الْحَسَنِ مُوسَى بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ ع...يَا هِشَامُ إِنَّ لِلَّهِ عَلَى النَّاسِ حُجَّتَيْنِ
>   حُجَّةً ظَاهِرَةً وَ حُجَّةً بَاطِنَةً فَأَمَّا الظَّاهِرَةُ
>   فَالرُّسُلُ وَ الْأَنْبِيَاءُ وَ الْأَئِمَّةُ ع وَ أَمَّا الْبَاطِنَةُ
>   فَالْعُقُولُ**
>
> Imam Kazim (peace be upon him) said to Hisham bin Hakam: O Hisham,
>   Allah has placed two kinds of authority over man:the apparent and
>   manifest authority and the internal and hidden authority. The prophets
>   and messengers are the apparent and manifest authorities and
>   intelligence is the hidden and internal authority. (Al-Kafi Volume 1.
>   Page 22.)

Intelligence is the hidden messenger with which no argument against Allah can be made just as mankind may not have any argument after sending of apparent messengers.

**The second group** does not deserve any punishment because they've done their utmost to seek the TRUTH but due to certain reasons they've failed to discover it. For instance they live in a country whose government is isolating people from hearing the true call of Islam through spreading poisonous propaganda against it.

> **لا يُكَلِّفُ اللَّهُ نَفْساً إِلاَّ وُسْعَها**
>
> **Allah does not task any soul beyond its capacity(2:286)**

Comment: Would the disbelievers of Quraish fall under the second group since Abu Jahl and 'Utba and others were spreading poisonous propaganda about Islam to them?

Answer (score 2):

Surah Al-Infal

> Verse (8:36) Indeed, those who disbelieve spend their wealth to avert [people] from the way of Allah. So they will spend it; then it will be for them a [source of] regret; then they will be overcome. And those who have disbelieved - unto Hell they will be gathered.

Surah Al-Nisa

> Verse 4:151 they are indeed the true disbelievers. And We have prepared for the disbelievers a humiliating punishment

There is no reward here after who disbelieve Allah, The Day, Angles, his Books and Messengers.

Whatever the good deed they do in this word will not suffice for that what they already enjoyed in this world.

Answer (score 1):

Allah can forgive all sins, no matter what. His mercy is enormous and no sin is bigger than his mercy. All you need to do is ask for forgiveness and ask it from the heart like you mean it. He will forgive you because nothing matches Allah (SWT) mercy.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE tha Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking [tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting [help](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) center.

Comment: @InterestingSubject, Allah can forgive all sins, except "shirk and disbelief" - please note this exception. If a person dies on disbelief in God, even though he was invited to Islam with proper knowledge, then his abode is hellfire forever. Allah only knows if a disbeliever deserves to be retested in the hereafter.